# How to load multiple matrices into a Chainer model using the iterator interface?

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix, chainer

I have a question regarding Chainer's iterator interface, and how it interfaces with a Trainer, Updater and Model.

My data are graphs, and hence are of varying matrix shapes. I have concatenated the features matrix into one large dense matrix, adjacency matrices into one large sparse COO matrix, and the summation operator into one large sparse COO matrix. Because this is done with molecular data, I have an atom graph and a bond graph per sample. Hence, the input data is a six-tuple, which for the purposes of deep learning, I consider to be one big giant data point for training. (Until I get this working with this giant matrix, I am not planning on doing train/test splits just yet, to keep my code simple.)

```
xs = (atom_Fs, atom_As, atom_Ss, bond_Fs, bond_As, bond_Ss)
ts = data['target'].values
dataset = [(xs, ts)]
```

My model forward pass is as follows:

```
# model boilerplate above this comment
def forward(self, data):
    atom_feats, atom_adjs, atom_sums, bond_feats, bond_adjs, bond_sums = data
    atom_feats = self.atom_mp1(atom_feats, atom_adjs)
    atom_feats = self.atom_mp2(atom_feats, atom_adjs)
    atom_feats = self.atom_gather(atom_feats, atom_sums)

    bond_feats = self.atom_mp1(bond_feats, bond_adjs)
    bond_feats = self.atom_mp2(bond_feats, bond_adjs)
    bond_feats = self.atom_gather(bond_feats, bond_sums)

    feats = F.hstack([atom_feats, bond_feats])

    feats = F.tanh(self.dense1(feats))
    feats = F.tanh(self.dense2(feats))
    feats = self.dense3(feats)

    return feats
```

I then pass everything into a Trainer:

```
from chainer import iterators, training
from chainer.optimizers import SGD, Adam

iterator = iterators.SerialIterator(dataset, batch_size=1)
optimizer = Adam()
optimizer.setup(mpnn)
updater = training.updaters.StandardUpdater(iterator, optimizer)
max_epoch = 50
trainer = training.Trainer(updater, (max_epoch, 'epoch'))
trainer.run()
```

However, when I run the trainer, I get the following error:

```
Exception in main training loop: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ericmjl/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 315, in run
    update()
  File "/home/ericmjl/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 165, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/ericmjl/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 177, in update_core
    optimizer.update(loss_func, *in_arrays)
  File "/home/ericmjl/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py", line 680, in update
    loss = lossfun(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/ericmjl/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/link.py", line 242, in __call__
    out = forward(*args, **kwargs)
Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before reraising the exception.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-ea26cece43b3> in <module>
      9 max_epoch = 50
     10 trainer = training.Trainer(updater, (max_epoch, 'epoch'))
---> 11 trainer.run()

~/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py in run(self, show_loop_exception_msg)
    327                 f.write('Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before '
    328                         'reraising the exception.\n')
--> 329             six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
    330         finally:
    331             for _, entry in extensions:

~/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

~/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py in run(self, show_loop_exception_msg)
    313                 self.observation = {}
    314                 with reporter.scope(self.observation):
--> 315                     update()
    316                     for name, entry in extensions:
    317                         if entry.trigger(self):

~/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py in update(self)
    163 
    164         """
--> 165         self.update_core()
    166         self.iteration += 1
    167 

~/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py in update_core(self)
    175 
    176         if isinstance(in_arrays, tuple):
--> 177             optimizer.update(loss_func, *in_arrays)
    178         elif isinstance(in_arrays, dict):
    179             optimizer.update(loss_func, **in_arrays)

~/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/optimizer.py in update(self, lossfun, *args, **kwds)
    678         if lossfun is not None:
    679             use_cleargrads = getattr(self, '_use_cleargrads', True)
--> 680             loss = lossfun(*args, **kwds)
    681             if use_cleargrads:
    682                 self.target.cleargrads()

~/anaconda/envs/mpnn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chainer/link.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    240         if forward is None:
    241             forward = self.forward
--> 242         out = forward(*args, **kwargs)
    243 
    244         # Call forward_postprocess hook

TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

This baffles me, because I have set up the dataset in the same way as the [mnist example](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/examples/mnist.html), in which the input data are paired with the output data in a tuple. Because of the layers of abstractions in Chainer, I'm not quite sure how to debug this issue. Does anybody have any insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `mpnn` model which gets only `xs` (or `data`) and outputs `feats`?
I think the problem is in the model, not the iterator nor dataset.

You need to prepare a model which gets `xs` and `ts` as input argument and calculate `loss` as output. For example,

```
class GraphNodeClassifier(chainer.Chain):
    def __init__(self, mpnn):
        with self.init_scope():
            self.mpnn = mpnn

    def forward(self, xs, ts):
        feat = self.mpnn(xs)
        loss = "calculate loss between `feat` and `ts` here..."
        return loss
```

and use this `GraphNodeClassifier` as optimizer's `setup` argument.

In the [MNIST example above](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/examples/mnist.html#prepare-the-updater) it uses chainer's built-in `L.Classifier` class which wraps MLP model (which only get `x`) to get `x` and `t` to calculate classification loss.